# Delete entire row based on sequence

Tags: excel, sequence, vba

I have some data dumped from MYOB that I need to sort. The data that is dumped by MYOB is in the following format:

- BSB Number:  000-000
- Bank Acct No: 123456789
- Bank Acct Name: Business Name

I have an if statement added to the right of these cells that return a 1 or 2 or 3 that I've determined to be the sequence.

Is there a macro or way I can delete the entire row of data if the sequence of 1,2,3 is not kept?

Example:

- BSB Number:  000-000                       1
- Bank Acct No: 123456789                    2
- Bank Acct Name: Business Name              3
- BSB Number:  000-000                       1
- Bank Acct No: 123456789                    2
- Bank Acct Name: Business Name              3
- BSB Number:  000-000                       1
- Bank Acct Name: Business Name              3
- BSB Number:  000-000                       1
- Bank Acct No: 123456789                    2
- BSB Number:  000-000                       1
- Bank Acct No: 123456789                    2
- Bank Acct Name: Business Name              3

The sequence must stay as 1 then 2 then 3. If it the sequence breaks, the row must be deleted.

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. When you say the entire row must be deleted, do you mean that if the sequence is 1 3 both of the rows with values 1 and 3 must be deleted? And if the sequence is 1 2 1 that that the rows with 1 and 2

Comment: Thanks chuff! Pretty much yeah. I need to keep the 1 2 3 sequence going, if it changes, the rows must be deleted. I have about 7600 rows of data from MYOB and I anticipate only have 1600 rows after the data is cleaned and kept to the 1 2 3 sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick VBA macro. Assuming your data is column C (=3).
It writes an "x" to column D if a row should be deleted

```
Sub sort()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For i = Columns(3).Find("*", [C1], , , , xlPrevious).Row To 4 Step -1

  Merge = Cells(i - 0, 3).Value _
        & Cells(i - 1, 3).Value _
        & Cells(i - 2, 3).Value _
        & Cells(i - 3, 3).Value

  If Merge = "4321" Then
    i = i - 3
  Else
    Cells(i, 4) = "x"
  End If

Next i
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Not perfect since the first 4 rows aren't sorted. But its a start.
Maybe others can improve the answer.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Nixda, it felt like it was working but all it did was leave the first 3 rows alone and delete everything else. Entire sheet wiped. :(

Comment: Well, do you understand what the macro is trying to do? I edited my answer so there is no deletion anymore. instead it marks them with a "x"

Comment: I think I copied the code when you had it based on the data being in column A. I just tried this is.. IT WORKS! You're amazing!! Its been running for a solid 10 minutes now, there's a good 7000+ rows to go through. Thanks heaps for this!!

Comment: This was only a proof of concept. if you set *screenupdating* to false, the code will run much faster.

Answer (score 0):

I really like your question and got kinda stumped - +1 for that!!

The only way I could come up with doing it was with a fairly ugly formula enumerating out your 3 possibilities.
Supposing you had your numbers in column B, beginning in cell `B1`, this formula would work from cell `B4` onwards (meaning you have to look at the first 3 results yourself).

```
=IF(OR(AND(B4=1,B5=2,B6=3),AND(B3=1,B4=2,B5=3),AND(B2=1,B3=2,B4=3)),TRUE,FALSE)
```

Then you can just delete out the rows where this formula returns a `FALSE` value.

I'll still give it more thought and try and think up of a more elegant solution, but this will definitely do the trick.

**EDIT (Based upon comments)**

To allow for a `4` as your screenshot shows, you start the formula in `B5` and it would be as follows:

```
=IF(OR(AND(B5=1,B6=2,B7=3, B8=4),AND(B4=1,B5=2,B6=3,B7=4),AND(B3=1,B4=2,B5=3,B6=4),AND(B2=1,B3=2,B4=3,B5=4)),TRUE,FALSE)
```

Comment: Or maybe do a data filter on the entire range, filter for the rows you want to keep, and copy and paste those to a different sheet. Then delete the original rows (if you don't want to keep them).

Comment: Is there a way I can add a screen shot of what I have so far... Filtering won't work

Comment: The idea (as a cleanup step) is to filter on your formula, @John.  Just a way to avoid hand-deleting individual rows. Another alternative would be to sort on your formula and then do the delete (If there are dups in the rows).  Would also need to add a sequence column running from 1 to n to preserve the original order, i.e. sort on your formula and this column.

Comment: Here is a example screenie of what I am working with. This is how MYOB dumps the data into CSV for me (its an old version of MYOB). There is one more field added now - Supplier.  - http://imgur.com/ewWnvPo - So basically I have the colored numbers to the right in Column C. They must stick to 1 2 3 4, in that sequence. So looking at that big chunk of 1s, they all need to be deleted so that the Column C sequence is 1 2 3 4. - I hope that makes sense... sorry!

Comment: ... The same formula would work, you'd just have to update it for the possibility of a `4` - One extra criteria per `AND()` statement and one extra `AND()` statement will do it.

Comment: Sorry John, everything comes up as False. I tried changing the formula to be for cells in C, but still everything is False.